# How to make sidebar close when any link is clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a Sidenav bar show when clicked on it but when it's showed I want to make it whenever any link is clicked it will close

Here is how I create a Side Navbar Open:

```
const App = (props) => {
    const [ menuOpen, setMenuOpen ] = useState(false);

    return (
        <HamburgerUlityItem>
            <InputNavbar type="checkbox" onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)} />
            <HamburgerLine />
        </HamburgerUlityItem>
           ...)

const SideNav = (props) => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {props.menuOpen ? (
                <HamburgerSize>
                    <AllItems>
                        <ListItems to="/product-category/top"> TOPS </ListItems>
                        <Item to="/product-category/top/t-shirt"> T - Shirts </Item>
                        <Item to="product-category/top/shirts"> Shirts </Item>
                        <Item to="product-category/top/hoodies"> Hoodies </Item>
                        <Item to="product-category/top/coats"> Jackets & Coats </Item>
                        <ListItems to="/product-category/bottom"> BOTTOMS </ListItems>
                        <Item to="product-category/bottom/pants"> Pants </Item>
                        <Item to="product-category/bottom/shorts"> Shorts </Item>
                        <ListItems to="/product-category/bag"> BAGS & BACKPACKS </ListItems>
                        <ListItems to="/about-us"> ABOUT US </ListItems> <ListItems to="/contact"> CONTACT </ListItems>
                    </AllItems>
                </HamburgerSize>
            ) : null})
```

How can I close the sidebar when click to any link ?

Comment: Is `SideNav` a child of `App` component? It's implicit, but, you are going to want to clarify your code

Comment: Yes `SideNav` is a child of `App` components

Comment: Ok please edit your question to include it. Also clarify if `Item` is wrapped in a [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments section, `SideNav` is a child of `App` component. So therefore, just pass down the state and state setter to `SideNav` and from there, when an `Item` is clicked, just set `menuOpen` to `false` or simply negate the state.

```
const App = (props) => {
    return(
        ...
        <SideNav menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen }/>
    )
}
```

On SideNav:

```
<Item to="/product-category/top/t-shirt" onClick={()=>{props.setMenuOpen(!props.menuOpen)}}> T - Shirts </Item>
```

Comment: No problem, but please edit your question for the benefit of future viewers who might have the same problem. Please refer to my comment on your question.